# Problemas al eliminar un archivo en ensamblador 8086

Tags: ensamblador

el motivo de este post es ver si se puede hacer algo en cuanto a este código, lo que pasa es que no puedo eliminar un archivo siempre y cuando la función 3CH para crearlo se ejecute con INT 21H, ya que hice pruebas y quite la ejecución de la interrupción para crear un archivo y si funciona la eliminación si coloco en NMF el nombre de un archivo directamente, y cuando vuelvo a probar ejecutando la interrupción de creación con el nombre directo en NMF deja de funcionar.

```
;Pedir el nombre del archivo
MOV AH, 0AH 
LEA DX, NMF
INT 21H
MOV BL, NMF[1]
MOV NMF[BX + 2], ' '

;Crear el archivo
MOV AH, 3CH  
MOV CX, 0H  
LEA DX, NMF + 2 
INT 21H
MOV HND, AX

;Cerrar el archivo
MOV AH, 3EH
MOV BX, HND
INT 21H

;Eliminar el archivo
MOV AH, 41H
LEA DX, NMF + 2 
INT 21H
```

NMF y HND están definidas de la siguiente manera.

```
NMF DB 100 DUP(' '), 0
HND DW 0
```

Y cabe mencionar el CF = 0 y AX = 00003 al momento de lanzar la interrupción para eliminar el archivo.
Espero y me puedan ayudar, gracias.